# Selector not called on selecting menu item after force touch

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos-2, wkinterfacecontroller

I have this code, for responding to a menu item being tapped after a force touch:

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {
    override init() {
        super.init()

        self.addMenuItemWithItemIcon(WKMenuItemIcon.Pause, title: "Pause", action: Selector("test"))
    }

    func test() {
        print("test")
    }
}
```

When I force touch, the menu appears. When I tap the "Pause" button, `test()` is not called.

Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Solved.

Though its the result of a silly mistake (aren't most problems?), I think this is something a lot of people will run into, so I'll keep it here with my answer.

I enabled force touch on the simulator, so I could show the menu. When I'm tapping again on the button, force touch is still enabled, so I'm force touching, thus dismissing the menu.

Solution: **Disable force touch before tapping a menu button.**

Comment: Saved me lot of time. Thanks

Comment: One of the best tips! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to comment with my thanks for this solution but I don't have the rep so I'll begin with, THANKS!

However I can also add an addendum to the solution by pointing out the shortcut keys are really handy here for switching between force press pressures.

⇧⌘1 - for shallow pressure (tap)

⇧⌘2 - for deep pressure (force press)

Make sure the iOS Simulator (watch) is focussed and you'll be good to go.

Comment: What you say is interesting, however It would probably be better to add that in a comment rather than an additional answer.

Comment: True, but I thought that was clear from my first sentance? _I wanted to comment with my thanks for this solution but I don't have the rep so I'll begin with, THANKS!_

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a small detail to make the SIM procedure more explicit because I actually saw this question and answer before and didn't perform it correctly because it wasn't totally obvious (to me at least).

1. Press ⇧⌘1 for all regular presses.
2. Press ⇧⌘2 before you use force touch.
3. Tricky part: After the menu item appears press ⇧⌘1 again **before** dismissing the menu item!