# Is it possible to query live HKUnit data directly from another class without passing data?

Tags: swift, watchkit

I have a custom `WorkoutSessionManager.swift` that does not subclass `WKInterfaceController`. It has its own context and protocol. It contains the query and sample updates. All the heart rate, distance and energy data (HKUnits) are printing to the console. This simple block outputs the data to the console.

```
guard let sample = activeEnergyBurnedSamples.first else{return}
        let value = sample.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(self.energyUnit)
        print(value)
```

I have a separate `Dashboard.swift` with my *mi*, *Cal*, *bpm* labels.

Since it is live data is it possible to query the HK data directly without passing this `value` property?

If this isn't possible how should I accomplish sending the `value` to my labels in the external class?

[image]
[image]

WorkoutSessionManager.swift

```
func createActiveEnergyStreamingQuery(workoutStartDate: NSDate) -> HKQuery? {

    guard let quantityType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned) else {return nil}
    let activeEnergyQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: quantityType, predicate: nil, anchor: anchor, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit)) { (query, samples, deletedObjects, newAnchor, error) -> Void in
        guard let newAnchor = newAnchor else {return}
        self.anchor = newAnchor
        self.addActiveEnergySamples(samples)
    }
    activeEnergyQuery.updateHandler = {(query, samples, deletedObjects, newAnchor, error) -> Void in
            self.anchor = newAnchor!
            self.addActiveEnergySamples(samples)
    }
    return activeEnergyQuery
}

func addActiveEnergySamples(samples: [HKSample]?) {
    print("updating calorie samples")
    guard let activeEnergyBurnedSamples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] else { return }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 

        self.currentActiveEnergyQuantity = self.currentActiveEnergyQuantity.addQuantitiesFromSamples(activeEnergyBurnedSamples, unit: self.energyUnit)
        self.activeEnergySamples += activeEnergyBurnedSamples
        self.delegate?.workoutSessionManager(self, didUpdateActiveEnergyQuantity: self.currentActiveEnergyQuantity)

        // Checks
        guard let sample = activeEnergyBurnedSamples.first else{return}
        let value = sample.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(self.energyUnit)
        print(value)
    }
}
```

DashboardController.swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var milesLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var caloriesLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bmpLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to query the HealthKit store for certain kinds of samples, and update your UI every time new samples are saved to the store.

You can do this in several ways, including by using [delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID276), [closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html), or [notifications](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/08/fundamentals-of-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift/). See below for sample code using delegation.

You've already defined a WorkoutSessionManagerDelegate protocol in your WorkoutSessionManager class (shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38711226/5352503)). If that protocol is the same as that used in [WWDC 2015 Session 203](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/203/), it provides methods such as `didUpdateActiveEnergyQuantity`, `didUpdateDistanceQuantity`, and `didUpdateHeartRateSample`. If you give WorkoutSessionManager an object that acts as a delegate, the manager can delegate UI management to that object using the methods provided by the delegation protocol.

In the principal class, WorkoutSessionManager, define a property to hold a weak reference to the delegate: `weak var delegate: WorkoutSessionManagerDelegate?`

Then, whenever new samples become available, call the corresponding delegate method. So, for example, in the `addActiveEnergySamples` function, you already have the following line: `self.delegate?.workoutSessionManager(self, didUpdateActiveEnergyQuantity: self.currentActiveEnergyQuantity)`

In the delegate class, DashboardController, adopt the WorkoutSessionManagerDelegate protocol: `class DashboardController: WKInterfaceController, WorkoutSessionManagerDelegate`

And in `awakeWithContext`, assign yourself as the manager's delegate: `wSM?.delegate = self`

Finally, in the delegate class, implement the methods provided by the delegation protocol, and make such changes to your UI as necessary based on the data passed through those methods.